# Convergence of sequence formed by the roots of a function at its singular point

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Consider a function $f(x,n)=\sum_{i=1}^m\frac{g_i(n)}{a_i-x}$ in which $a_m>a_{m-1}>\cdots>a_1=1$ and $g_i(n)\geq 0$ for all $i=1,\cdots,m$ and $n=1,2,\cdots$. (By the way, $a_i$ is a constant and $g_i(n)$ is a function of $i$ and $n$). Meanwhile, I have $\sum_{i=1}^m g_i(n) = G$, which is a positive constant that's independent of $n$.

I'm interested in the roots to $f(x,n)=0$, which is denoted as $x_k(n)$. We know that there are $m-1$ distinct real roots of $x_k(n)$ as $g_i(n)\geq 0$, and $x_{k}(n)\in[a_k,a_{k+1}]$ for $k=1,\cdots,m-1$. Due to the properties of $g_i(n)$, I am able to show that the sequence formed by $x_k(1),x_k(2),\cdots$ is a monotonic sequence as $n$ increases. And since $x_k(n)$ is bounded, it will converge to a limit as $n\to\infty$.

However, there is a flaw to go from the sequence being bounded+monotonic to it being convergent. This is because $f(x,n)$ is not continuous at $a_1,a_2,\cdots$. If $g_k(n)=0$, or if $g_k(n)$ approaches to $0$ as $n$ increases, then $x_k(n)=a_k$, which is one of the singular points. **In this case, we can only say that $x_k(n)=a_k$ "converges" to a limit point/accumulation point, is that correct? Is it still possible to prove convergence for the sequence $\{x_k(n)\}$ when $g_k(n)$ approaches $0$ as $n$ increases?**

Thanks a lot for your input and help!!!

---

Of course, if $g_k(n)$ is strictly positive, then I can actually bound $x_k(n)$ away from $a_k$ and $a_{k+1}$ so that I'm always within the interval of continuity for $f(x,n)$.